# XMLHttpRequest send не передает информацию

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Делая запрос, функция *send* не передает информацию.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", <?php echo "\"" . $linkToClient . "\""; ?>, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("bannerid=" + redirect);
```

аналогично с:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "new-client.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("bannerid=1");
```

При помощи *php* проверяю ссылку, результат: *localhost/js/client/new-client.php*, а должно быть *localhost/js/client/new-client.php?bannerid=1*. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что вы ожидаете параметр в параметрах запроса(get), а они передаются в теле запроса(post). Попробуйте выполнить `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: @vp_arth, благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы ожидаете параметр в параметрах запроса(get), а они передаются в теле запроса(post).

Попробуйте выполнить: `var_dump($_POST)`

А чтобы добиться ожидаемого поведения, параметры придётся передавать в метод open:

`xmlhttp.open("POST", "new-client.php?bannerid=1", true);`

Comment: Спасибо, проблема и была в том, что отправлял POST, а проверял GET.